# Создание специально меню меню joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla, меню

Изучаю joomla 3, выполняя дипломный проект. Возник вопрос. 
Необходимо реализовать меню, где для авторизованных одни пункты, для не авторизованных другие, и для администрации другие:
[image: меню]

На месте "пользователь" должно быть его имя, а в выпадающем пункте доступные для его уровня доступа пункты.
Стандартный модуль не подходит и в общем то искать в интернете не хочется. Необходимо ли реализовать, из-за того что нужно получать имя пользователя, модуль или можно в шаблоне создать?

Answer (score 0):

А причём тут модуль? Доступы к меню для разных групп пользователей устанавливается именно в меню, см. скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения, за не точный вопрос. поправил.
Я знаю что так можно. по началу так и хотел. но потом оказалось нужным указывать имя пользователя как пункт.

Comment: Готового решения, насколько помню, нету, надо пилить и переделывать стандартный модуль. Пример кода тут не показать )) это глобально

Comment: Вот и я думаю, что нужно. По моему мнению, для моего проекта можно это сделать в шаблоне. Но тут у меня возникает другая проблема, это как указать ссылки на другие страницы